# Nameservers updated but still shows NXDOMAIN when querying

Tags: domain-name-system

I've changed my nameservers from Freenom's to Cloudflare ones, but however it's been a few hours now and WHOIS does show the nameservers have been changed to Cloudflare ones, but when you use the `nslookup` command via Terminal it would show NXDOMAIN. What's the problem?

Original Nameservers: ns1.freenom.com, ns2 etc.

New Nameservers: desi.ns.cloudflare.com, guy.ns.cloudflare.com

Edit:

`dig` Command Output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> pizzajustice.tk
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 4618
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pizzajustice.tk.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tk.         5   IN  SOA a.ns.tk. joost\.zuurbier.dot.tk. 1644234137 10800 3600 604800 5

;; Query time: 99 msec
;; SERVER: 192.0.2.2#53(192.0.2.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 07 19:42:37 CST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no DNS propagation, this is a myth.

You are not giving the actual name involved so noone can help you. Your options are to ask your DNS providers for help or use online troubleshooting tools like DNSViz.

Note however that Freenom domain names, especially the free ones, are special in the sense that you can't change the nameservers. This should be explained to you by the registrar you used to register them. You may not be in this case as you seem to say the change is reflected in whois, but anyway it is important to have this in mind.

You are also not showing what commands you use to test (and `dig` is better than `nslookup` FWIW). If you query a recursive nameserver, it is normal, expected and as designed that you don't see the change immediately, because that recursive nameserver cache has probably been populated by data, maybe from your own tests before the change, so it won't have the new data until the TTL expires.

If you query the registry authoritative nameserver you can assess if the change has been indeed published, irrespective to what recursive nameservers have in their caches.

Comment: There has always been a nameserver changing section in Freenom domain management area, I've been using Freenom domains with Cloudflare for over 4 years and apparently this problem never occurred before on me. I consider this problem pretty weird since WHOIS did show that the nameservers are correct ones, but when querying with websites or commands it would show nothing.

Comment: "There has always been a nameserver changing section in Freenom domain management area" It depends on the TLD (but since you didn't disclose the name involved, no one knows the TLD either). As for the rest it seems you did not read my answer outlining the difference between authoritative and recursive nameservers. Also whois is not really a tool for troubleshooting DNS issues. You should query registry authoritative nameservers to see what they publish. While rare, there may be discrepancies between whois and DNS, and DNS is authoritative (on DNS stuff), not whois.

Comment: I read the entire answer, but I'm just confused with your points, first it's easy to see that my edited question contains the output therefore contains the domain which you're probably asking for, second I don't think any DNS helping tool can help as the domain registrar should handle nameservers update just like usual.

Comment: "second I don't think any DNS helping tool can help " You are entitled to your own opinions, but on that you are wrong.

Comment: "that my edited question contains the output " Which is useless as you don't show the `dig` command you did precisely (hence not understanding the **crucial** difference between authoritative and recursive nameservers).  Had you really read the response you would have tried DNSViz that would have shown the problem clearly even if you don't believe any tool can help you, and you would have seen you also need to query the authoritative nameservers and not any random one as you probably dig (again you are not showing your command...) which would have give you the same useful reply as DNSViz.

Comment: ok https://dnsviz.net/d/pizzajustice.tk/servers/ and `dig pizzajustice.tk`, is this what you're asking for??

Comment: ok so I did `dig @8.8.8.8 +nssearch pizzajustice.tk` and it returns nothing, but when returning my other working domains it does return nameservers. I don't really think it's a client-side problem more like it's a server-side issue which I can't do much about it. I'm doing every step to change nameservers just like usual but it doesn't work this time.

Answer (score 0):

name servers (`a.ns.tk`, `b.ns.tk` etc) for `.tk` `TLD` don't have `NS` records for `pizzajustice.tk.` domain.

Comment: Yeah that was kinda the point, because I did change the nameservers but they don't get updated like my other domains did.